Proving $2^m-q^n=1$ has no solutions, for integers $m \ge 2$ and $n \ge 2$, with $q$ an odd prime
How can one prove the following theorem?

Theorem. The equation $2^m - q^n = 1$ has no solutions where $m \ge 2$ and $n \ge 2$ are integers and $q$ is an odd prime.

One suggested proof idea was based on examining the $(mod\,\,4)$ values of $2^m$ and $q^n + 1$.  Of course, $2^m \equiv 0\,\,(mod\,4)$ when $m \ge 2$.

Just state Catalan's conjecture.

I am pretty sure that an easier proof is desired. Of course , Catalan's conjecture (now a theorem) answers the question.
